# Некоректный ответ на http запрос

Tags: php, http

Интегрирую платежную систему onepay, при оплате сервис обращается к моей странице и получает

> ERROR: Server not responding

Хотя через браузер получаю корректный ответ.

Адрес, к которому обращается сервер (и к которому обращался я через браузер)
http://frontend.anysign.tv/site/paymentfinish

К сервису оплаты я обращаюсь путем http запроса, там формируется форма оплаты в зависимости от параметров запроса. После - сервис оплаты обращается ко мне на сайт, чтобы уведомить меня о том, прошел платеж или нет. Ответ формируется php функцией `actionPaymentfinish()`.

```
public function actionPaymentfinish() {
  echo json_encode(array(
         "status" => "true",
         "pay_for" => 55446,
         "signature" => sha1("check;tru‌​e;55446;1q2w3e4r5t6y7u")));
}
```

На этом этапе платежная система получает

> ERROR: Server not responding.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А какими технологиями вы пользуетесь, чтобы обратиться к сервису? Какой язык программирования? Покажите код.

Comment: К сервису оплаты я обращаюсь путем http запроса, там формируеться форма оплаты в зависимости от параметров запроса. После, сервис оплаты обращаеться ко мне на сайт( уведомить меня о том прошел платеж или нет) , он обращаеться и ответ формируеться php функцией   public function actionPaymentfinish(){
        echo json_encode(array("status"=>"true","pay_for"=>55446,"signature"=>sha1("check;true;55446;1q2w3e4r5t6y7u")));
    }    на этом этапе платежная система получает ERROR: Server not responding

Comment: Ну так добавьте детали в тело вопроса.

Comment: В вашем примере не совершается HTTP-запроса, не очень понятно, где вы ловите такую ошибку

Comment: Мне почему то кажется что гейт ходит к вам по https а он у вас не обрабатывается

Comment: "не совершается HTTP-запроса"-да, он совершаеться платежной системой, потому я не могу его показать, а ошибку я вижу в личном кабинете(там есть, что-то вроде logs)

Comment: Послушайте куда к вам ломятся при помощи сниффера (tcpdump || Wireshark)

Comment: Да, тоже хотел сказать. Возможно, к вам обращаются по другому адресу, не по тому, который способен принять и обработать ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. укажите тип контента Content-Type: application/json
2. возможно платежная система тыкается в https а не в http
3. если кодироdка UTF-8 попробуйте удалить BOM